# Publications Citing Physics SE?

Tags: discussion, citation, publishing

What publications (papers, books, etc.) have cited questions or answers of Physics StackExchange?

Comment: Related meta discussions: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6949/2451 and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6299/2451 Related MO.SE question: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/13917

Comment: I'm unsure why this is downvoted - this is a legitimate question, even if it is not particularly easy to mine for the answer. As a comparison, the thread [Best of MathOverflow](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow) shows a bunch of papers that cite MO (indeed, that explicitly come out of MO threads). This is not MO but there's no reason why there can't be papers that cite this site.

Comment: I think I might have cited it in my thesis, but I'm not sure that counts as it was never published (and I'm biased :-P)